# Notation Question about Murphy's Machine Learning Textbook

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, hidden-markov-model, notation

I am currently on chapter 17 about Hidden Markov Models and Kalman Filter, but I am a bit confused over the notation that he uses. For instance on page 608, he uses the notation for prediction using the kalman filter as: $$p(\mathbf{x}_{t+h} | \mathbf{x}_{1 : t}) = \sum_{z_{t+h}} p(\mathbf{x}_{t+h}|z_{t+h})p(z_{t+h}|\mathbf{x}_{1:t})$$

The model assumes that there is a discrete-time, discrete-state, markov chain, with $z_{t} \in \{1 , \ldots, K\}$ plus and observation model of $p(\mathbf{x}_{t}|z_{t})$. It then states that if the observations are continuous, it is common for the observation model to be a conditional gaussian given by $$p(\mathbf{x}_{t} | z_{t} = k , \mathbf{\theta}) = N(\mathbf{x}_{t} | \mathbf{\mu}_{k}, \mathbf{\Sigma}_{k})$$

Now I am wondering if we can condition $\mathbf{x}_{t+h}$ on multiple other time series as well similar to a vector autoregressive model but with the kalman filter applied to it. So whether the notation $\mathbf{x}_{1:t} = \{ x_{1,j}, x_{2,j}, x_{3,j} \} $ for $ j = 1:T$

Or does he simply use the above notation to specify a model such as $x_{t} = \mu_{t} + e_{t}$, where $\mu_{t+1} = \mu_{t} + \epsilon_{t}$, where the kalman filter is only applied to its own individual series. That is I understand how to apply the kalman filter to an individual series and to forecast future predictions but is it possible to apply the kalman filter not only based on 1 individual series but rather, multiple other features with their time series included as well ?

Hope my question is clear, and would greatly appreciate some clarification.

Comment: Should the $x_{1:t}$ in the condition on the left hand side be  $\mathbf{x}_{1:t}$?  Other than that, typically the Kalman filter is defined for vector ($\mathbb{R}^n$) states and vector ($\mathbb{R}^m$) measurements  so it's unclear what is unclear here (I don't have the book in question). Though if the state here is discrete, this is not a "Kalman filter" so something strange / different terminology is going on anyway

Comment: @JuhoKokkala I have corrected the mistake so it should be $\mathbf{x}_{1:t}$, actually another question about $\mathcal{R}^{n}$ states, so to put it in the context of some simpler model such as linear regression then would the states simply correspond the the continuous values that we are trying to predict ?

Comment: If you have another question, it should be posted as a separate question. For this question, could you add the definitions of $z_t$ and $\mathbf{x}_t$ and perhaps the model used here

Comment: I have just done so